# Transaction never mined after one day and new transactions were mined since should I worry for the first transaction appearing again?

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet

Can someone explain what technically happens here?
It might be to specific to myEtherWallet, but I am confused and worried that this stuck/nonexistent transaction would suddenly go through.

On myEtherWallet I sent some ETH yesterday as a bugbounty reward. I got a transaction hash. Each time I check I get TRANSACTION NOT FOUND.
The ETH is still in my account.

I am trying to be patient ;)

This is it, no reason to hide, it's all public anyways: 
https://www.myetherwallet.com/?txHash=0x1e9b3ad9a9179fba873934484a11259e3febca11dfa9e696c43b3d542e996198#check-tx-status

I have made several transactions since. Can I consider the transaction dead and safely issue another?

What could cause this? the myEtherWallet node dropping it or not getting through to the etherum plattform? Evil cryptokittens?

Comment: If afterward you have sent other transactions that were mined, then that transactions effectively is gone. Each transaction is numbered with consecutive integers, check in etherscan your mined transactions should have consecutive numbers.

Comment: I think that's the answer, Ismael. I did send transactions afterwards and so the nonce of the transaction I originally tried to send is invalid - so that one will never go through. Perhaps it should be posted as a real answer, or I delete my Q if it wasn't a good fit for this forum.

Comment: The question is good for me, I've edited the title to reflect the real issue here. You can add an answer with your results.

Comment: Ismael, please post as answer so I can accept it. The only answer posted here, although good, was not the right one. Good edit btw, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If after the missing transaction you have sent other transactions that were mined into the blockchain then the first transaction is likely replaced by one of the more recent ones.

Each transaction from the same account are numbered with consecutive integers starting from zero (technically it is called *nonce*). You can check in a blockexplorer that your mined transactions have consecutive numbers.

You can't have two transaction from the same account with the same nonce it is forbidden by the Ethereum rules. Usually miners will choose the transaction with higher fee.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as you said, evil [cryptokittens](https://www.coindesk.com/loveable-digital-kittens-clogging-ethereums-blockchain/) are clogging the network recently.

High transaction demand increased the gasprice. Your transaction will be discarded if you sent it with too low gasprice. If you want to be sure it's cancelled then [here is a guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/72tctz/guide_how_to_cancel_a_pending_transaction/) on it but likely it will be rejected by itself.

Try resending your transaction with higher gas price. You can get an idea about the network status and required gas price from here: https://ethgasstation.info/